# getting rawPassword cannot be null while creating auth by json consumption?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my Secuiry by using SecurityFilterChain and providing PasswordEncored but still have an error which I will provide in the next block

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurity {

    private final RecipesUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SpringSecurity(RecipesUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

}
```

and here is the detailService

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RecipesUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findById(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        return new RecipeUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

and getting error like this in the run terminal and i don't really get what is wrong in my code

```
2023-04-21 04:41:09.574 ERROR 404954 --- [nio-8822-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:107) ~[spring-security-crypto-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at recipes.service.UserService.add(UserService.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at recipes.controller.RegistrationController.register(RegistrationController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
```

I was sending auth via spring security, sending json request like this in Controller

````
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void register(@JsonView(UserJsonView.RegistrationView.class)
                             @Valid @RequestBody User user){
        userService.add(user);
    }```

here is service

    @Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public void add(User user) {
        if (userRepository.existsById(user.getEmail())) {
            throw new KeyAlreadyExistsException();
        }
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public void addTest(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}

User

    @Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @Email(regexp = "^(?=.{1,64}@)[A-Za-z0-9\\+_-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9\\+_-]+)*@"
            + "[^-][A-Za-z0-9\\+-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9\\+-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$")
    @JsonView(UserJsonView.RegistrationView.class)
    private String email;


    @Size(min = 8)
    private String password;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<Recipe> recipe;
}
````

Answer (score 0):

The user object being submitted to `register` does not have the password field populated.

The code you show here looks fine.

Either the page is not populating the password field or there is something wrong with the UserJsonView.RegistrationView class. Can you add it to the question.

Also, I need all the annotations on the `resister` method. Logically it’s a PUT or POST but I don’t see the annotation.

The html page calling `register` would be helpful.

Please add more code and a System.out.println(user) in `register` and add the output to the question.

I suspect that the next step is for me to simulate. I will need enough code to do that.

Comment: oh my bad there is the service I will add